# ViewController's properties are nil

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make SideMenu.
my code of `HomeViewController`:

```
lazy var sideMenu: SideMenuViewController = {
   let menu = SideMenuViewController()
    menu.stayViewObj = self
    return menu
}()
```

Menu button's Action:

```
@objc func handleMenuBtn () {
    sideMenu.openMenu()
}
```

SideMenu's `viewDidLoad` :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        constraintLeadingPropertiesView.constant = -viewSelectProperties.frame.width
}
```

SideMenu's `openMenu` method:

```
 func openMenu() {
        debugPrint(">>>>openMenu")
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let yCoordinate: CGFloat = statusBarHeight + 44.0

        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        view.alpha = 0
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeMenu)))
        view.frame = window.frame

        startFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinate, width: 0, height: window.frame.height - yCoordinate)
        view.frame = startFrame!

        window.addSubview(view)


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.alpha = 1
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoordinate, width: window.frame.width - 80, height: window.frame.height - yCoordinate)

        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now, I am getting `constraintLeadingPropertiesView`=`nil` and all other properties of SideMenuController are also `nil` accepting `stayViewObj`.
so get crash on `viewDidLoad`.
how to solve this... any suggestion also helpful for me..
Thanks!

Comment: are you using segue?

Comment: pls post error logs

Comment: no, not using segue, just want to add sideMenu as Subview of Window @MahendraGP

Comment: probably you are accessing vc property before it memory allocation.

Comment: yes...thats the problem  @MahendraGP

Comment: I also try performSelectorAfter Delay of 1 sec but..still got crash @MahendraGP

Comment: what is `viewSelectProperties`? @IBOutlet or just a variable.

Comment: Its IBOutles of UIView @MahendraGP

Comment: write `constraintLeadingPropertiesView.constant = -viewSelectProperties.frame.width` in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172563/discussion-between-uday-babariya-and-mahendra-gp).

Comment: Guess: `SideMenuViewController` has a whole "UI" in Interface Builder and so has a Xib or a Storyboard associated. Doing this `SideMenuViewController()`, by default, is just doing `SideMenuViewController.new()` (in pseudo code). That's doesn't do SideMenuViewController.init(nibName: "something", bundle: nil)` if it's a Xib, nor, `UIStoryboard.init(name: "SoundTest", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? SideMenuViewController` (if it's the initial one). It's not the same. You are not initializing the ViewController with the "UI".

Comment: yes...its working @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to `instantiateInitialViewController` instead of create object via `lazy Var`.

```
let menu = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? SideMenuViewController
```